# After last update Unity no longer works

Tags: unity, 13.10

An hour ago I installed latest updates and now Unity doesn't work anyomore, I only see desktop with icons. Manually searching I opened system monitor and found out only 400 Mb of RAM is taken which means complete Unity is turned off. Can someone help me to fix this.

Since I'm crippled I probably won't be able to provide you with all details you need because I don't have window borders, no right click menu, nothing, only Nautilus.

Comment: Read second answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/297375/unity-and-ubuntu-desktop-disappeared-and-i-am-unable-to-reinstall-it

Comment: First command works, but second reports something about I have to input valid URI

Comment: It seems Unity is not working on my account, when I log in as Guest everything is ok. For now I'm using Gnome Shell until I find solution for Unity

Comment: Try reinstalling it. Take a look here, 1st answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/95458/how-do-i-reinstall-unity

Comment: Tried, but no effect. It seems something is wrong with my account, because when I create another user Unity is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by renaming compiz config folder. Location of this folder is: `/home/username/.config/compiz-1` After renaming it restart your computer and compiz will create new folder with default settings. 
when I booted my computer, I still coulnd't see Unity so I opened Nautilus, searched for ccsm in /usr/bin/ and activated Unity plugin manually.