# Unity launcher won't hide

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

first question asked on this site. Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 from wiping the HDD, had it installed before with the same hardware and didn't have this issue.

For some reason I'm unable to hide the launcher or change the icon sizes. I browsed through some old questions on here and it seemed a lot of people were running Unity 2D, is there any way to check if I'm using it? My GPU is an ATI Radeon HD 6870, I tried both proprietary and open drivers, but I didn't have this issue previous install just yesterday.

When I first sign in the launcher flashes purple also, if that could help. Have nothing installed besides what comes with a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully by now this error has subsided. If not, I have a few suggestions for you.

**First** - If you haven't already, update Ubuntu.

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

If that doesn't help, [this guy had a problem with Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368137/after-last-update-unity-no-longer-works), which was fixed by **renaming the compiz config** folder here: `/home/username/.config/compiz-1`

1. You will have to restart your PC after you do this. If Unity doesn't start you will have to start it up manually.
2. If that doesn't work you can reset Unity.
   **To Reset Unity and Compiz**

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

3. And if that doesn't work you can restart Unity.
   **To Reset Unity and Compiz**

> setsid unity

If Unity is still failing you, you can try your luck with **GNOME 3.10**
A full installation guide can be found [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10).

If all else fails, you can format your HDD again and do a **fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10**. If you used a Live CD the first time I suggest you burn a new copy in case your files were corrupted during the first burn. Good luck.